# iphone html css tutorials

Tags: iphone, html, css

I am trying to find some good introductory short tutorials that show how to build web site suitable for iphone brwoser. I am not having any success. Google is not turning up useful sites. please let me know if you are aware of any.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at:

- [Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/)
- [iPhone Development: 12 Tips To Get You Started](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/iphone-development-12-tips)